# More elegant arr in Python

Tags: python, arrays

I would like to make this code more elegant

```
lis = [line.split() for line in filecsv]
arr = [None] * 8
for i, x in enumerate(lis):
   arr[0], arr[1], arr[2], arr[3], arr[4], arr[5], arr[6], arr[7] = arr[1], arr[2], arr[3], arr[4], arr[5], arr[6], arr[7], x
```

I don't like the last line.
How can I do? Thanks

Comment: Can you please explain what are you trying to do in this, and can you please share some sample data of filecsv, it will be helpful for further suggestions. thanks

Comment: Does the above code give the proper output?

Comment: `arr = [None] * 7; arr.append(x)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you have, this seems to work:

```
lis = [line.split() for line in filecsv]
arr = [None] * 8
arr[:-1]=lis[1:]
arr[-1]=lis[-1]
```

For the specific problem of taking the last 8:

```
lis = [line.split() for line in filecsv]
arr=lis[-8:]
```

That said, depending on what you need for it, checking to see if there are 8 lines could be helpful. If there aren't 8 lines available, it will take everything currently available

Comment: I have a csv file with 100+ lines. I have to take the last 8. Just as you did I take the first ones. How can I solve? The idea is beautiful

Comment: If you enjoy the answer, please mark it as solved or upvote it.